# How to get Friends uid from tagged photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I can get names from field "text" of table "photo" but
I cant use those names to get uids.

How can I get uids of tagged people in photo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you have to do is query the graph api like this :
`https://graph.facebook.com/{photo_id}` 
and you will recieve the data you need...

```
{
"id": "{photo_id}", 
"from": {
   "name": "{user_that_uploaded_the_photo}", 
   "id": "123"
}, 
"tags": {
"data": [
  {
    "id": "123", 
    "name": "Lior", 
    "x": 48.5099, 
    "y": 37.5276, 
    "created_time": "2011-10-11T05:50:35+0000"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "456", 
    "name": "Shlain", 
    "x": 19.0397, 
    "y": 35.3201, 
    "created_time": "2011-10-11T05:50:40+0000"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "789", 
    "name": "Abigail", 
    "x": 76.8212, 
    "y": 47.4614, 
    "created_time": "2011-10-11T05:50:32+0000"
  }
 ...
```

You can use the [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to experiment with these methods...
good luck!

Comment: I think so. just found out 3 min after your post ><